# Insert an XSLFTetxRun in a specified position using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, apache-poi-4

I am currently working on a Document Management System using Apache POI in which I have to replace certain placeholders from XSLFParagraph text. Previously using XWPFParagraph, I was able to insert an XWPFRun on a specified position e.g.,

```
XWPFRun beforePlaceholderRun = paragraph.insertNewRun(start);
```

The above code insert run in a paragraph on a specified position i.e., start. I couldn't find any functions that inserts an XSLFTextRun in a specified position of XSLFTextParagraph. E.g., the below code insert an XSLFTextRun in the end of the paragraph

```
XSLFTextRun placeholderRun = paragraph.addNewTextRun();
```

But what I want to achieve is to insert an XSLFTextRun on a specified position of an XSLFParagraph when the XSLFParagraph is comprised of multiple XSLFTextRun. Can anybody please guide me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide you with an exact solution for your problem, but some hints might help you out (I had a pretty similar issue).

The question is what kind of element you are showing in your screenshot. If you say it is neither a paragraph nor a table, then it might be an embedded file? In the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/) there is a method to fetch those:

[getAllEmbeddedParts()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPN9n.png)

Also, check out this repo which I found when I was solving a quite similar problem (maybe you find something helpful for your case as well):

https://github.com/deividasstr/docx-word-replacer